# @FrameworkEndpoint to oAuth 2.0 revokeToken

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0

I have a @FrameworkEndpoint based controller in order to implement DELETE of token as follows

```
@FrameworkEndpoint
public class RevokeTokenEndpoint {

    @Resource(name = "tokenServices")
    ConsumerTokenServices tokenServices;



    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.DELETE, value = "/oauth/token")
    @ResponseBody
    public void revokeToken(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String authorization = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        if (authorization != null && authorization.contains("Bearer")) {
            String tokenId = authorization.substring("Bearer".length() + 1);
            System.out.println("tokenId : " + tokenId);
            tokenServices.revokeToken(tokenId);
            //tokenStore.removeRefreshToken(token);


        }
    }

}
```

My request is a DELETE (http://localhost:8081/oauth/token request with Authorization Bearer ce8b914d-57db-4ad7-86d9-be2d7f47b203

The problem is that the end-point does not get hit at all and the message returned back is "unauthorized". When I fire the request with Authorization Basic with client_id and secret then it does hit the end-point. But then in that case I will be forced to pass another parameter or header to carry the token and change the code to get the value of token from this another parameter or header.

I believe, the ideal way would be tell spring security to allow unauthorized calls to remove the access token. Does this make sense ? and if yes then how ?

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented like this

```
@PostMapping("/token/revoke")
    public ResponseEntity<Boolean> revokeToken(
            @RequestHeader(value = "Authorization") final String tokenId) {
        try {
            final String[] token = tokenId.split("\\s+");
            tokenServices.revokeToken(token[1]);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(true, HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            LOGGER.info("Exception while removing access token");
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
```

*tokenId* contains Bearer *b133b6ee-59db-4809-b546-e47cb879bea1*. In this way i have implemented and its working fine